# Associative Array where a class TypeInfo is key in D?

Tags: class, d, associative-array

I'd like to be able to create an multidim associative array where one dimension is a class. Like this:

```
class Node{
    Node[?classType?][string] inputs;
}
```

so that I later can do

```
Node[] getInputsOfType(?? aClass){
   if(aClass in this.inputs)
      return this.inputs[aClass];
   else
      return null;
}

// meanwhile in another file...

Node[] effects = someAudioNode.getInputsOfType(AudioEffect);
```

I'm just lost. Any ideas?
Regarding the last part: Can a class be used as a parameter all by itself like that? (`AudioEffect` in this example is a class.)

BR

**[update/resolution]**

Thanks for the answer(s)!

I thought it'd be nice to post the result. Ok, I looked up `.classinfo` in the source code and found that it returns an instance of TypeInfo_Class, and that there's a `.name`-property, a `string`. So this is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env dmd -run
import  std.stdio;
class A{
    int id;
    static int newId;
    A[string][string] list;
    this(){ id = newId++; }
    void add(A a, string name){
        writefln("Adding: [%s][%s]", a.classinfo.name, name);
        list[a.classinfo.name][name] = a;
    }
    T[string] getAllOf(T)(){
        return cast(T[string]) list[T.classinfo.name];
    }
}
class B : A{ }
void main(){
    auto a = new A();
    a.add(new A(), "test");
    a.add(new B(), "bclass");
    a.add(new B(), "bclass2");

    auto myAList = a.getAllOf!(A);
    foreach(key, item; myAList)
        writefln("k: %s, i: %s id: %s",
                key, item.toString(), item.id);

    auto myBList = a.getAllOf!(B);
    foreach(key, item; myBList)
        writefln("k: %s, i: %s id: %s",
                key, item.toString(), item.id);
}
```

It outputs:

```
Adding: [classtype.A][test]
Adding: [classtype.B][bclass]
Adding: [classtype.B][bclass2]
Trying to get [classtype.A]
k: test, i: classtype.A id: 1
Trying to get [classtype.B]
k: bclass2, i: classtype.B id: 3
k: bclass, i: classtype.B id: 2
```

So yeah, I suppose it works. Yey! Anyone has ideas for improvement?

Are there any pitfalls here?

- Can `classinfo.name` suddenly behave unexpedictly?
- Is there a »proper» way of getting the class name?

Also, is this the fastest way of doing it? I mean, all class names seems to start with `classtype.`. Oh well, that's perhaps another SO-thread. Thanks again!

BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ClassInfo](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/object.html#Classinfo) class (accessible through the `.classinfo` property) to refer to class types at runtime. However, the `ClassInfo` class doesn't implement the necessary methods to be used in an associative array (see the [D reference page on AAs](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/hash-map.html) regarding using classes/structs in AAs). I suppose this is possible if you implement your own wrapper for ClassInfo that can be used as an AA key. This should be fairly simple, as you can expect that a class type will have only one ClassInfo instance, thus you can simply use the ClassInfo's address as the unique hash.

---

By the way, a simpler and faster way to write

```
if (key in aa)
    return aa[key];
else
    return null;
```

is

```
auto pvalue = key in aa;
return pvalue ? *pvalue : null;
```

Comment: Re each class only having one classinfo: IIRC that might not be true if you are using DLLs or SOs. But in those cases you end up with other problems as well.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using the `.name`-property in the classinfo, which is just a string, so that was no problem using in an associative array, although it feels like it could be faster. /BR